# Downloading files from Sharepoint to File System using Databricks

Tags: python-3.x, azure, pyspark, sharepoint, databricks

> We have the following python code **already working like a champ** in one of our environments:

```
def download_files_to_dbfs (site_url, file_url, dbfs_path):
  try:
    # Credentials for accessing SharePoint
        credentials = ClientCredential("Client-ID?",
                                       "Client-Secret?")
        ctx = ClientContext(site_url).with_credentials(credentials)

        # File_url is the sharepoint url from which you need the list of files
        list_source = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(file_url)
        files = list_source.files
        ctx.load(files)
        ctx.execute_query()

        for myfiles in files:
            rel_url = myfiles.properties["ServerRelativeUrl"]
            download_path = dbfs_path + myfiles.properties["Name"]

            with open(download_path, "wb") as local_file:
                 file = ctx.web.get_file_by_server_relative_path(rel_url).download(local_file).execute_query()
                 print("Downloaded file " + myfiles.properties["Name"])

  except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

We have been granted our own workspace, where we are essentially the administrators.
The issue is that even though our **SharePoint admin** has already set up a client secret connection to SharePoint, we still can't access SharePoint using the same function by switching to our new `Client-Secret` and `Client-ID`.
In the code above, I placed `"Client-ID?"` and `"Client-Secret?"` within quotation marks because I'm not sure about the correct order or whether these two are the required elements for establishing the connection between SharePoint and Databricks.
The error we encounter is `Acquire app-only access token failed`, with no additional details provided, only the error message itself. We have been struggling for weeks now :(...

Comment: Few considerations that might help:

a) Print the exception stack trace with traceback to try to get more details about the failure.
b) If you're using library https://pypi.org/project/Office365-REST-Python-Client/#Working-with-SharePoint-API, the order of client id and secret in your code are correct.

c) You should avoid writing to DBFS since Databricks will deprecate it.

d) You might also want to check threads https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/401398/sharepoint-add-in-failure-to-acquire-app-only-toke and https://github.com/pnp/pnpframework/issues/336.

Comment: A): After importing traceback and adding it to the function, I get a long better description of the error... But all in all, the core issue here seems to be that my code is unable to establish a network connection, meaning that it's not even accessing the SharePoint resources.... B) Yes I am, thanks. C) After doing my reasearch, my understanding is that databricks will only deprecate DBFS for init scripts. D) These resources didn't quite help :(

Comment: If you haven't, you can validate/confirm it is a network connectivity related issue by running %sh ping -c 3 <sharepoint host name> in a notebook cell.

Comment: I'm running it like this:

%sh ping -c 3 https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/commondata

and I get:

ping: unknown host


So I don't know whether I'm doing it right or not

Comment: I still think this might be a firewall issue... I'll check with my IT Team and update you on this shortly.

Comment: So after adding the traceback to my python function and using only the BASE URL in your ping suggestion (without the sites/commondata), I realized this was definitely a firewall situation, so I contacted my IT Firewall guys and they spent over an hour resolving my issue and now my functions is working like a charm :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After @Evandro de Paula kindly advised me on how to proceed, I have finally concluded that this was a firewall issue. How? I added the traceback to my function to detect further details of the error... I hope this helps someone else too.